# FlatList scrollToIndex typescript expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to set up scroll to index on a flatList based a variable with typescript.
Examples I've found are with react and doesn't seem to work with what I have at the moment.

My project actually has two flatlists and I want the scroll to dynamically move based on what is selected.
Below is a simplified example of what I have, just want an idea on how to make it work first. But obviously not working.

```
    <FlatList

      //tried this, but don't know how to pass the actual index
      ref={(ref) => { ref?.scrollToIndex({index: 0}) }}

      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => onSelect(item, index)}
          > 
           <View>
           </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        
      )}}
    />
```

onSelect function, dont know how to pass the index back to the flatList

```
const onSelect = (item, index) => {
  //scrollToIndex(index)?
}
```

Some guidance would be appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

```
const onSelect = (item, index) => {
    //scrollToIndex(index)?
    scrollToIndex({animated: true, index});
}
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, i tried that but it's giving me an `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.flatListRef')]` error.
I console Logged, `this` and it's undefined (typescript, not react native)

Comment: says `Cannot find name 'scrollToIndex'`, which makes sense because `onSelect` is just a function, wouldn't know it's being called from flatlist